# Latest Single Page Application framework

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

please help me to find out what is the latest framework that fit for developing single page application. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd downvote this more than once if I could.

Comment: This is a great question. Unfortunately, it's not a good fit for Stack Overflow's purpose. Stack Overflow works best for questions that ae specific requests for help on programming topics. Asking for frameworks or libraries tends to elicit opinions and lead to flamewars - which we'd all like to avoid on S/O. Thus this question is likely to be closed very soon as part of Stack Overflow's question policy. In future - it's best to stick with questions that match S/O's preferred format :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please be more specific when asking questions. :)

If your **goal** is to augment web-based applications with model–view–controller (MVC) capability,then I recommend you to use Angular js or Backbone js.

You can use Angular js http://angularjs.org/ .**AngularJS** is an open-source JavaScript MVC framework.
This tutorial http://www.revillweb.com/tutorials/angularjs-in-30-minutes-angularjs-tutorial/ is very good for beginners and it's very easy.

And **Backbone js** http://backbonejs.org/ is also a good framework.Backbone.js gives structure to web applications by providing models.this http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/ tutorial is also a good one for starters.

If you are struggling to choose any framework please read this article http://readwrite.com/2014/02/06/angular-backbone-ember-best-javascript-framework-for-you#awesm=~oymdu8WAUkUbdV